# Security of environment variables on front-side in SvelteKit

Tags: security, environment-variables, sveltekit

I heard that environment variables (e.g. VITE_DATABASE_URL) on front-side is not secure in SvelteKit.

I want to check for myself that this is not safe. I inspect the elements on Chrome DevTools, but I couldn't find any insecure things.

Can you please prove me that environment variables on front-side is really insecure?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should assume that anything that's on the frontend can be read by your client because, by definition, it's on the *front end*.

What you should do is write your own endpoint that's *server side*, call your endpoint from client-side code and connect to your database from your server-side endpoint.

[Here's a nice introduction to endpoints](https://joyofcode.xyz/sveltekit-endpoints). Cheers!